# datatable.rows.count always returns 0

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm creating a simple web service to authenticate a user.

I have a problem filling the datatable(used to store the results of a select statement) properly, 'dt.rows.count' (dt is the name of the datatable) always returns 0 even if the select statement returns nothing. I've tried clearing the datatable before filling it, and after the if condition as well, but to no avail, I get the same result.

Would really appreciate any advice on how to proceed.

```
[WebMethod]
    public string Authen(string a, string b)
    {
       var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER-SQL;Initial Catalog=DECA-DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****");
       var sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Login_Matrix WHERE Username = ' " + a + " ' AND Password = ' " + b + " '", con);
        var dt = new DataTable();

        con.Open();
        dt.Clear();
        sda.Fill(dt);            
        con.Close();
        int x = dt.Rows.Count;
        //return (x);

        if ( x >0)
        {
            dt.Clear();
            return ("In");
        }

        else
        {
            dt.Clear();
            return ("out");
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you close the `sqlconnection`

Comment: close your sql connection after else part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a space after and before the single quotes makes your query search for inexistant user names and passords (like " Steve ") and it return no records

A quick fix could be

```
var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Login_Matrix 
                               WHERE Username = '" + a + "' 
                                 AND Password = '" + b + "'", con);
```

but this is very dangerous.
This code is vulnerable to [Sql Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).
You should use parameters

```
var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Login_Matrix 
                              WHERE Username =  @uname 
                                AND Password = @pwd", con);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@uname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = a;
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@pwd", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = b;
```

And on the same line about security, another thing to consider as soon as possible, is that storing plain text password in your database is a really big security risk. You should search [how to salt and store an hash of the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

There are other parts of this code to improve.

- First you need to have using statements around the disposable objects
  like the connection or the command.
- Second, there is no need to have a full SqlDataAdapter and a
  DataTable to just check if the user exists or not.

So you can rewrite your code as:

```
string cmdText = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Login_Matrix 
                   WHERE Username = @uname AND Password = @pwd)
                   SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0";

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("....."))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con))
{
    con.Open();
    int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return ( result == 1 ? "In" : "out");
}
```